# Kalman filter for slow ground vehicle with RTK

Tags: ros, kalman-filter, gps, sensor-fusion

I have been using dual [RTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Kinematic) receivers for my tractor projects.  This gives me reliable position, heading, and tilt at low rates (10 Hz).  I recently began working with an [INS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system) (an [Advanced Navigation Spatial Dual](http://www.advancednavigation.com.au/product/spatial-dual)) and it's wonderful to get a full Pose from a single device at up to 1000 Hz.  The problem I have is that an INS like this is expensive (~$12K) and total overkill for what I'm doing (driving on ground at 5.5 MPH).

Is there a way to achieve an adequate result using [FOSS](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi9i5Ofx-nZAhWO3KQKHcwdB1cQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFree_and_open-source_software&usg=AOvVaw1XrL6000OuArhpMY7SYlmy)?  The articles I find on Kalman filtering seem to always assume that the NavSatFix does not provide sufficiently accurate absolute position data.  RTK, however, does provide sufficient accuracy and precision for my needs.

Note that while I do have radar ground speed available, my strong preference is to just use RTK receivers and a MEMS [IMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit).  Let's say that I want specifications comparable to my Spatial Dual but the update rate doesn't need to be over 100 Hz.

Update:  I found [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6297/fa369b62109fa3cbb482280b2fb8d1467a38.pdf) which addresses the constraints of a (slow land-based non-holonomic) vehicle.

Comment: What does FOSS stand for?

Comment: How accurate does this need to be?

Comment: FOSS = Free and Open-Source Software @holmeski

Comment: Any sensor will have finite precision, so the RTK will as well.

Comment: If the Kalman filter options you were looking at can deal with the case where position estimates aren't accurate/precise enough, perhaps they can deal with your apparently easier case too? If not, I think we'll need more info on your requirements to answer the question.